# Auto-populate a worksheet if a condition is met in the previous sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to auto-populate a worksheet if a condition is met in the previous sheet. I used the IF function but it doesn't return the right value.

[image: Screenshots for question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you want to show the client name of the sheet "Meeting Tracker" in the sheet "Deal Tracker". So you have to use it in your formula, too:

```
=IF(('Meeting Tracker'!E5="OT", 'Meeting Tracker'!D5,"")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting my formula.Could you help me with another issue, how do I populate the corresponding columns to that particular client name. For eg.- In the Deal Tracker sheet, "Transaction Type" column is common between both the sheets, so how do I get that data to be auto-populated along with the client name.              Also, the Transaction Type column in the Meeting Tracker sheet is a data validated column with multiple selection. When it gets auto-populated in the Deal Tracker sheet, the multiple values aren't spaced out or appear one below the other.

Comment: You have to use the same schema: '<SheetName>'!<Celladdress>.